# I want to deploy a Strapi application with IIS, how do I do that?

Tags: iis, strapi

How to deploy an application using Strapi and IIS. I know that a web.config is needed, but I can't get it to work.

I used a web.config file with a node project configuration but it didn't work. I received an "iisnode encountered an error when processing the request."

Comment: Node.js based web apps should be hosted with HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-nodejs-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: This error may occur by missing permissions. Have you tried giving IIS_IUSRS full permissions? Node.js based web apps deploy to IIS also needs url rewrite and arr modules. As Lex said, it should be hosted with HttpPlatformHandler. Or you can refer to this link: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deploying-strapi-windows-server-without-using-process-nitali-mittal?trk=articles_directory.